# Transpile ES2015 gives `export` error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a class as follows

```
export default class Test { 
     constructor() {}
}
```

Now, I would like to transpile this

```
$> ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node test.js -o test-es5.js
function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export default class Test {
                                                          ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
...
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
         "es2015",
         "stage-0"
    ] 
}
```

Any suggestions why this is not possible ?

Comment: Maybe  a stupid comment, but did you also install the presets with npm?

Comment: Yes I did: "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",

Comment: And `.babelrc` is in your current working directory? Also, the name `babel-cli` is a bit unexpected, as the `babel-cli` _package_ installs an executable called `babel` (without the `-cli` suffix).

Comment: Sorry, its a typo, I use `babel-node`, thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong Babel executable.

`babel-node` is meant as a replacement for the Node interpreter, to run .js files directly. It's *not* meant to be used as a transpiler.

The `-o` option for `babel-node` is interfering with the settings in your `.babelrc`, causing the error.

Easy fix: use `babel` instead of `babel-node`.